# Send XML request from Rails application. XML model payment implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, post, request, payment

I am working on the implementation of a payment system on my website. But as the payment system works according to the old model, all requests go through XML. I need to send XML (the code is attached below) to the URL and get a response. How could i send XML post request with Ruby on Rails. I need to send in to this url https://setmpos.ykb.com/PosnetWebService/XML?xmldata=%3CposnetRequest%3E%0D%0A++%3Cmid%3E... Where xmldata is query parametr.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
<posnetRequest>
   <mid>6700000067</mid>
   <tid>67000067</tid>
   <tranDateRequired>1</tranDateRequired>
   <sale>
     <amount>2451</amount>
     <ccno>4506349116608409</ccno>
     <currencyCode>TL</currencyCode>
     <cvc>000</cvc>
     <expDate>0703</expDate>
     <orderID>1s3456z8901234567890123</orderID>
     <installment>00</installment>
   </sale>
</posnetRequest>
```

Comment: If its SOAP use [savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) if not there are also probably a boatload of gems that can read WSDLfiles  and generate XML based on a hash. If it some home rolled junk and none of those apply then you can render a XML view and send it with any the many HTTP libraries available for Ruby. The key takeaway here is that this is not something built into rails and will require work and research on your part.

Comment: Sending a GET request with a whole XML document in the query string is absurd though. If you're using XML for a payment system you should be using POST request and placing the XML in the body of the request.